# Returning True and False (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some functions that are behaving erratically:

```
pos = [' '] * 9;
def defense_ai():
    #if statement
    if pos.count('X') > 1:
        #various other if statements
        if statement:
            #statement
            a = 5;
        #...
    else:
        return False;
    pos[a] = 'O';
    raw_input('Done!')
    return True;
def offense_ai():
    #statement that doesn't matter
    pass;
def main():
    defense_ai();
    if not defense_ai():
        offense_ai();
main();
```

My problem is, `raw_input('Done')` is executing, but then `offense_ai()` runs. This shouldn't happen because `defense_ai` is supposed to return `True` right after `raw_input` is called. To check out what `defense_ai()` returns, I added a `raw_input()` just before the `if not defense_ai()` statement.

```
raw_input(defense_ai());
```

The result of this is `False`. The `raw_input('Done!')` does appear, but it returns False after all.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What's with the semicolons at the end of the lines? This isn't `C`.

Comment: Are you aware that you're calling `defense_ai()` twice? `if not defense_ai()` will call the function again.

Comment: Just having `def main(): if not defense_ai()` would call it once and return a boolean for your `if` statement. The result isn't being stored in any way. I don't see from this post why this would cause your issue, but I suspect that there's more to this code you haven't posted.

Comment: I guess the part of the code I posted, in the end, isn't enough for you to help me... hmm...
Edit: The comment about running defense_ai() twice really helped. It seems only running defense_ai() once makes the program work perfectly fine. Thanks!

Comment: @ZeroFunter Glad it worked. I put a longer explanation as an answer. It might help. If not, you might want to add some of the code you left out and post a more detailed answer yourself, for anyone else that stumbles across this.

Comment: No offense, but semicolons and using raw_input for printing kinda makes you look like you don't know what you are doing

Comment: About the raw_input()... Actually, I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game and, if I just print the string, it is simply going to run cls() afterwards(which clears the screen) and print again the grid with the updated positions, so I won't be able to see what has been printed. That's the reason I use raw_input(). As for the semicolons, well, that's just how I like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a suspect section of code:

```
defense_ai();
if not defense_ai():
    offense_ai();
```

It seems like you've misunderstood, calling `defense_ai()` on a line by itself doesn't do anything with the value it returns. You need to assign it to something in order to use the return value, like this:

```
defenseResult = defense_ai();
```

in which case that is likely what you'd want to use for your `if` statement.

```
if not defenseResult:
    offense_ai();
```

The thing is, calling `defense_ai()` even in an `if` statement, will cause the code of the function to be executed, so your code is running twice and creating confusion. However, you can use this instead to not bother assigning the return result, and call `defense_ai` just once as part of the `if` statement.

Like this:

```
def main():
    if not defense_ai():
        offense_ai();
```

Just remember that if you ever see `()` at the end of a variable name that means a function is being executed (or else you have syntax error)

Comment: Instead of that, I took away the first defense_ai(), so that only the if statement runs the function. Thanks for the help!